# Batch Timeout /nobreak constant response

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe

How do I get my batch file to use `timeout /nobreak` without displaying in the program *"waiting for one seconds, press CTRL+C to quit"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the command's output to the Nul device like this:

```
TIMEOUT 1 /NOBREAK >NUL
```

For most commands, adding `>nul` to the end of the command will redirect the command's standard output to the Nul device which simply discards the output. Some output, particularly error output will still be written to the screen.

If you'd like to pause indefinitely, use:

```
PAUSE >NUL
```

Or can go one step further and provide a custom message:

```
ECHO Press your favorite key to continue...
PAUSE >NUL
```